# offset in gridmap

Tags: slam, mapping, occupancygrid

colleagues, i am currently viewing Cyrill Stachniss's course on SLAM and also doing the exercises. At the moment i am doing an exercise on occupancy grid mapping and there is some strange offset variable in the code and i don't know what is the purpose of it

Here is the code related to it

```
border = 30;
robXMin = min(poses(:,1));
robXMax = max(poses(:,1));
robYMin = min(poses(:,2));
robYMax = max(poses(:,2));
mapBox = [robXMin-border robXMax+border robYMin-border robYMax+border];
offsetX = mapBox(1);
offsetY = mapBox(3);
mapSizeMeters = [mapBox(2)-offsetX mapBox(4)-offsetY];
mapSize = ceil([mapSizeMeters/gridSize]);
```

This offset is then used to convert world coordinates into map coordinates

```
pntsMap = floor((pntsWorld - repmat(offset,1,size(pntsWorld,2)))./gridSize)
```

Comment: I believe we may need some more detail in order to be able to answer this question.

Can you provide more input in terms of the source of `border`, `poses`, and what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: This is the task of mapping with known poses. I have data with laser beams(angles and distance) to build the map. poses - robot poses in 2d (x,y,theta). About border i do not have any additional information.